# Regex Pattern to get Salesforce standard object supported calls not working

Tags: regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

This regex pattern works everywhere except in Apex. Can anyone help me with this

```
Http httpProtocol = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
String endpoint = 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/get_document_content/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_profileskillshare.htm/en-us/244.0';
request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
String jsonString = response.getBody();
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
Pattern tag_pattern = Pattern.compile('(?m)(?=<samp class=\"codeph nolang\">)(.*?)(?=<\\/samp>)');
system.debug(tag_pattern.pattern());
String s = String.valueOf(m.get('content'))
    .replaceAll('\\n','')
    .replaceAll('<(hr|br)\\s?>','<$1/>')
    .replaceAll('<!-- -->','');
Matcher patternMatcher = tag_pattern.matcher(s);
system.debug(patternMatcher.group(1));
```

I am trying to get Salesforce Apex Standard supported calls
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm
They are contained in tag called 
`<samp class="codeph nolang">{text}</samp>`

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
Http httpProtocol = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
String endpoint = 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/get_document_content/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_profileskillshare.htm/en-us/244.0';
request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
String jsonString = response.getBody();
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
Pattern tag_pattern = Pattern.compile('(?m)(?=<samp class="codeph nolang">)(.*?)(?=</samp>)');
system.debug(tag_pattern.pattern());
String s = String.valueOf(m.get('content'))
    .replaceAll('\\n','')
    .replaceAll('<(hr|br)\\s?>','<$1/>')
    .replaceAll('<!-- -->','');
Matcher patternMatcher = tag_pattern.matcher(s);
while(patternMatcher.find()) {
    system.debug(patternMatcher.group(1));
}
```